# Understanding the effect of each parameter in a Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: normal-distribution, simulation, monte-carlo

I am running a Monte Carlo simulation where I sample from Normal Distributions associated with parameters E11, E22, and GIC to get the plot in red which can be seen in the figure below. The figure below also shows the Normal Distributions for the cases where **only** E11 has uncertainty, whilst the other parameters are kept constant and likewise for E22 and so on. I am basically trying to understand the effects of each of these parameters on the uncertainty in the red curve. From the graph below all I can tell is that E11 and GIC have enough of a standard deviation to be influencing the red curve. I was wondering if there is any other information I could obtain from this graph and the data given below?

*Is this a sensible way of assessing the relative effects of each parameter on the 'overall solution' as depicted by the red curve?* Should I be considering other ways to determine this?

**Edit**:
[image]

**Data**
E_11    $\mu$ =0.004332,
$\sigma$ = $2.1374×10^{-4}$

E_22    $\mu$ =0.004314,
$\sigma$ =$2.6348×10^{-5}$

G_1C    $\mu$ =0.005005, 
$\sigma$ = $7.0475×10^{-4}$

Uncertainty in every parameter $\mu$=0.004265 ,
$\sigma$= $6.6933×10^{-4}$

Comment: Because of the confusion expressed in extensive comments to some of your previous questions, please note that the vertical axis is *not* a "probability of occurrence." It *should* represent probability per unit value on the x-axis. If the notation (at the bottom right corner) of "$\times 10^{-3}$" is to be believed, however, then all the values on the vertical axis are orders of magnitude off from what they should be. This may be related to noticeable inconsistencies among your graphs, all of which should have the same areas. That makes one wonder what your graphs are really displaying.

Comment: @whuber Thanks. I have replotted the curve and have checked that the Areas are all 1. Could I get your opinion on how each of these parameters may be affecting the _red_ curve, based on this figure? Is this easily discernible?

Comment: @whuber I have also added some relevant data at the bottom of the graph. Cheers.

Comment: @whuber Thanks. From this information, is there a way to determine the relative effect of each parameter on the _red curve_?