# Effect of each parameter on a Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: linear-model, monte-carlo

I was wondering what is the best way to determine the effect of each random parameter on the result obtained from a *Monte Carlo Simulation*.

I realise I have asked a similar question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91467/understanding-the-effect-of-each-parameter-in-a-monte-carlo-simulation), but this time I am making this question in a more general manner as I didn't get any answers previously.

**Background**: I'm essentially running a Monte Carlo Simulation where I sample randomly from 65 Normal Distributions and 2 Uniform Distributions. Then, i then input these values to a linear equation and run this for 500.000 iterations. I just wanted to determine the best way to establish the relative effect of each of these 67 (in total) random variables on the final outcome from my Monte Carlo Simulation.

Comment: Sorry, why use so many iterations?

Comment: @lsanchez I needed to have very strict confidence intervals for the data and as I have a high-performance computer at my disposal I thought that there was no harm.